# A local variable value is empty after processed and filled with data in asmx web service method

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, soap

I have created an asmx web service and call a web method with its parameters using SOAP UI for testing. I used two parameters and they are both generic lists with custom types. In the method, I process them and after process operation, depending on condition, I store those values in a new generic list variable. That new generic list variable, is defined in method as local variable. That variable is my return value of the web method. Until this point, there is no problem.

I call the web method in my local developer machine, the method returns value correctly as i expected. But when I installed the web service in IIS and called the related method using SOAP UI again, the method's return value comes empty.

Couldn't understand what causes this kind of error here? Variable value is lost in method or what?

Comment: You can debug your service which is hosted on your iis and detect the problem. There is a way to do that with visual studio.

Comment: Also you check iis log.

Comment: IIS Server is located as production server. There is no way to install there VS platform. Also i checked the iis log. But there is no meaningful data out there. it just shows which IP called the service, and etc... I believe it's something like losing values in method... it's just like after postback in asp.net, if you don't put values in session, it loses value after page is loaded again! Just an opinion, can i define those local variables in a custom class and use it from there? Because the problem is data is not stored method inside variables.

Comment: If i were you, i would publish service in my iis locally and debug it then.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Kostas! I'll give it a try as you advised! Let's see what happens!

Comment: If you have time comment the results. Just for curiosity. :)

Comment: No error, Kostas! I debugged the service that is on local host IIS. Attached the process via VS 2008 and after debugging, it worked successfully. No problem occurred! worked as expected! now we are back to where we started :) all these operations is applicable on remote host IIS, too? any idea?

Comment: what a silly mistake that I've made! Actually I've never thought that  the error is caused by the request parameter value! Service codes are correct but the request parameter! I just understood that after thorough code analysis! Thanks for the efforts, Kostas!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for whom I make busy with the problem! The error is caused by the SOAP request parameter value... It's all working correctly now! sorry again!